# Different Details on Previous Passport

Tags: passports, indian-citizens

I am a Indian citizen whose name is GivenNames: AA BB LastName: CC (Indian passports have no MiddleName field). I got my first passport when I was 14 with the details as GivenNames: AA BB CC and blank LastName. My parents did not pay attention to this problem and being a minor, I didn't know better. I travelled to Singapore, Thailand and Germany during this period.

When I turned 18 and applied for a new passport, I filled out the renewal form and a new passport was granted with GivenNames: AA BB LastName: CC (which is perfect). I use it for all travel now (I am now 27) and have traveled to Turkey, US and South Korea.

For any visa question asking "Have you ever used a different name?" I have answered "No" (because I didn't know about this discrepancy till a few days ago when my mother gave me my old passport).

**Will this discrepancy between my new and old passport ever cause me problems? Is there something I should do at this point of time?**

Answer (score 3):

Well, I can't guarantee that it will "never" cause you problems, but **it's very unlikely to**.

1. Your *name* has not changed, your new passport just corrects a clerical error.
2. You have not returned to any of the countries that would potentially have records of you entering with your old passport.
3. You were already allowed entry into Turkey, US and South Korea, they're not going to notice anything afterwards.

If you want to play it absolutely 100% safe, for Singapore, Thailand and Germany (Schengen) only, you could note your old passport name for the "Have you ever used a different name?" question.  Everywhere else, you will be fine listing your correct name only.